# Website Viewed on Android - Landscape view -Defaults to Tiny Full Website

Tags: android, css, iphone, media-queries

When we view our website on an iPhone, iPad it looks fine in both portrait and landscape view. When we view it with Android it looks fine in portrait view, but when we view it in landscape view, it shrinks down to about a 100p x 100p square. And its the full size website, not the mobile version. We've tried a device resolution detection media query with no luck. 
Before I post any code can anyone suggest where I should be looking? I still think its a media query issue, but I'm stumped.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks Warren for the comment before.

Comment: Are you doing a min-width media query on the website? If so, landscape mode may be reporting a width larger than the minimum. Is this a custom WebView or in the browser?

Comment: Yes, both min and max. The error only happens on the Android. Everything else looks good. I wonder, can overlapping media queries cause this issue? I'm trying not to step on someone elses toes.

Comment: Is the website public? I could take a look, if so.

Comment: Its an intranet site. Ill see if I can move a page out so you can see it.